# javax.inject,version=[0.0,1) -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle, javax, aem-6

Is there any other work around to fix the `javax.inject,version=[0.0,1) -- Cannot be resolved` issue in OSGI bundle

I have tried all the approaches provided in the below forum. but still my bundle doesn't resolve.

I am using AEM 6.2 + Java version: 1.8.0_121 + Apache Maven 3.3.9 and archetypeVersion=10

And my code can be found at my [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NnB5JL8ei6RFBVQ1ZUV0RwdHc/view?usp=sharing)

http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__fikl-ive_just_updatedfro.html

[image: Javax inject]

Comment: What does your AEM instance show in Package Dependencies (http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder) for javax.inject?

Comment: @i.net it is `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
 <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 6):

In core pom.xml file add **Import-Package** tag for "**javax.inject**" with "**version=0.0.0,***" inside "**org.apache.felix**" plugin tag like below [Tested on AEM 6.2 working perfect]

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <!--
       <Embed-Dependency>
          artifactId1,artifactId2;inline=true
       </Embed-Dependency>
      -->
      <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
      <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>

      <Sling-Model-Packages>
        com.next.sample_test_impl.core
      </Sling-Model-Packages>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
<artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

from parent and child(bundle) pom.xml,because javax.inject.inject is exported by this dependency as well .So your code is considering this dependency but not

```
     <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
           <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

So if u will remove the sling.model.api dependency,it will take its correct dependency.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, after so many rebuilds with modification of pom files finally found it works  with `<dependency><groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId><artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId></dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>      
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
</dependency>` as mandatory in build and remaining `uber-jar` and `geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec` jars as optional. even both together works.

Comment: @VAr it works for me only with o‌​rg.apache.sling.mode‌​ls.api and javax.inject dependencies.